# Where are the Linux file system files stored in a Ubuntu 11.04 guest OS using VMWare player 4.0.2

Tags: vmware-player, ubuntu-11.04

I am using a Ubuntu 11.04 Linux Virtual machine Image using VMWare Player 4.0.2. This Ubuntu image is without any VMWare tools.

Now if I create/download any files using Ubuntu on its file system, it shows it is inside /home/user, but where is it stored on my harddisk so I can access them using my host OS(Windows-7).

How can one do that?

Are VMWare tools needed to be installed in the guest OS for this?

Answer (score 3):

The are within the VMDK file.  You genally don't access them directly from the host.  You need to you networking to access the VM.  Something like winscp would be a good/easy tool.

Comment: So is it like one has to power on the Virtual Machine. Then using winscp, are you saying one has to then use Winscp client on Windows Host to ftp to the Ubuntu guest OS(For that I guess Ubuntu needs to be running a ftp/scp server isn't it) Also what IP address or hostname  should one use in winscp to make this ftp/scp connection to ubuntu?

Comment: To use scp/sftp, you just need to install the OpenSSH server. The IP address completely depends how your network is setup.  The paid version of Vmware Workstation has a tool that allows you to mount a VMDK, when the VM is not running.  There are some third party tools, but I have never used them.